# Mysql query with left joins - NULL records being implicitly type converted

Tags: mysql, left-join

Just investigating a MySQL query which is returning more records than it should.

The basic query is:

```
SELECT
    a.id                AS parent_id,
    b.id                AS child_one_id,
    c.*
FROM
    parent                          AS a
    LEFT JOIN child_one             AS b ON a.id = b.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN child_two             AS c ON (
        a.id = c.parent_id
        AND c.user_id = '1234'
        AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
    )
WHERE (
    a.user_id = '1234' OR c.parent_id IS NOT NULL
);
```

I.e. the parent table is left joined to two child tables, there's no relationship specified between the two child tables, and there's a filter being applied to only return results where the user owns the record OR the user is linked to the record via child_two.

As I understand it for LEFT JOINs, if the database can't find a matching record in the right-hand table, it will generate an "empty" record with all values set to NULL.

However, in this case, it's generating some records where the "empty" record appears to have been through an implicit type conversion.

```
# parent_id, child_one_id, id, parent_id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
     27    ,     29      ,   ,          ,           ,           , 
     27    ,     32      ,  0,         0, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 
     27    ,     47      ,  0,         0, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 
     30    ,     26      ,   ,          ,           ,           , 
     30    ,     46      ,  0,         0, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00,
```

I.e. for some records, it's generating a "NULL" record for child_two, but for others, it appears to have performed a type-conversion to create a "zeroed" record for child_two.

(and before anyone asks, no, there aren't any records in child_two which have an id of zero!)

I've also proven that there's two ways to stop the zeroed records from being generated:

1) Remove child_one from the query

2) Change child_one's join to "`LEFT JOIN child_one AS b ON (a.id = b.parent_id AND b.user_id = '1234')`"

However, this doesn't explain why this type-conversion is being triggered, or why it's only triggered for some records.  And sadly my best attempts to exercise my google-fu have failed to dig up any potential explanations.

So, while I've already got a solution to address the issue, I'd still very much like to understand why/how the "zeroed" records are being created -  we use "`LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x.id IS NULL`" in a number of places!

UPDATE:
I've managed to reproduce the issue on some temporary-table clones with the number of columns cut down and a minimal number of records in each table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faa3d0/1

With the above SQL, I've been able to reproduce the issue on multiple schemas on our production server.  **However, it isn't happening on our test or development servers, nor is it happening on the sqlfiddle**.

So this seems specific to our production server.

One interesting point is that if I drop the primary index on child_two, the issue stops occurring.  Though the explain plan shows that the query is still using the "job_id" index to retrieve the data.

Currently, we're running on the following MySQL versions:

- Production: 5.7.11-4-log (Percona Server (GPL), Release '4', Revision
  '5c940e1')
- Test: 5.7.21-21 (Percona Server (GPL), Release '21',
  Revision '2a37e4e')
- Dev: 5.7.21-21 (Percona Server (GPL), Release
  '21', Revision '2a37e4e')

And sqlfiddle runs on MySQL 5.6.

This suggests that this is an issue in the 5.7 stream of Percona, which was addressed at some point after version 5.7.11-4.  However, I can't see any potential candidates in the release notes.

We are due to upgrade our production servers in the near future, so hopefully this issue will be addressed.  In the meantime, if anyone is able to identify the patch which addressed the issue (and/or any configuration which could be used to mitigate the issue), that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Looking at those guidelines, I've provided a result set and shown my "best efforts" to date, as well as the fact that I have a solution (which doesn't explain the cause). I could potentially try to provide the table schemas - the child tables are small/basic, but the parent table has 113 columns and I'd have to spend some time on sanitisation.

If it'll help, then I'll gladly do so, but they're all innodb/latin1 and the behaviour is inconsistent.

I'm currently trying to reproduce the issue with some temporary table clones; if that turns up anything useful, I'll update the question.

Comment: Rest assured, if i didn't think it would help, I wouldn't have asked. Remember to consider the 'M' part of MCVE.

Comment: I can reproduce with minimalist clones of the original tables - i.e. "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x AS SELECT y". http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/550732/1

I'll see if I can produce a data-set which can reproduce the issue - there's about 20k records between the 3 tables, which is a bit much for a sql fiddle!

Comment: A dozen thoughtfully chosen rows is usually enough to illustrate the point.